# How to log all Dio traffic to Sentry

Tags: flutter, sentry, dio

In my Flutter app, we're using

- dio: ^5.1.1
- pretty_dio_logger: ^1.1.1
- sentry_flutter: ^7.3.0

The problem is that pretty_dio_logger [internally uses a loop](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/pretty_dio_logger/blob/f1ab4e4ff39b755c56a38d1daff335bcec0bb28f/lib/pretty_dio_logger.dart#L187) to print the requests/responses line by line. As a result, **each line is considered a standalone breadcrumb** in Sentry. So an issue in Sentry looks something like this:
[image: Sentry issue example]
Which is very useless, especially when some response is too big which will result in hundreds of breadcrumbs.
What I want is, for each request/response to be considered a single breadcrumb.

I tried using the [recommended package](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dart/configuration/integrations/dio/) sentry_dio, but it only send logs about the request's performance and parameters. I didn't see any configuration to make it log any more data (like the response body for example)

My Sentry configuration is almost all defaults:

```
await SentryFlutter.init(
      (options) {
        options.dsn = FlutterConfig.get('SENTRY_DSN');
        options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
        options.environment = flavor.name;
      },
      appRunner: runApp,
    );
```

So before I start implementing a custom solution (forking pretty_dio_logger or something like that), I want to ask whether I'm missing something in the above mentioned libs? or is there some standard approach for http logging in Sentry?

Comment: I'm having this problem too - I don't get any detailed logs about requests with Sentry Dio. Did you manage to solve it in the end?

Comment: @frabcus No I haven't :/  Please let me know if you find something.